# Spring Retryable annotation ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I would like to use `@Retryable` annotation for `restTemplate`. I've added:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

as well as `@EnableRetry` to config class. I've marked method:

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

with (in a new thread)

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts=4,value=Exception.class,backoff=@Backoff(delay = 2000))
```

But I'm getting error from catalina:

```
27-Oct-2017 18:11:41.023 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Around
    at 
<ommitted>
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Around
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Around
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.<clinit>(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 70 more

27-Oct-2017 18:11:41.038 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

**EDITED:**
I moved a little bit forward. Found that [Spring Retry makes use of AOP](http://www.mscharhag.com/spring/spring-retry) so I added:

```
<dependency>
  <groupid>org.springframework</groupid>
  <artifactid>spring-aop</artifactid>
  <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I'm getting different error:

```
27-Oct-2017 21:11:12.071 SEVERE [http-nio-8088-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file [(...)\HomeController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy
    <ommitted>
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAopProxyFactory.createAopProxy(DefaultAopProxyFactory.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport.createAopProxy(ProxyCreatorSupport.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:468)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:349)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 35 more
```

To isolate the problem I created small `springMVC` project and it's the same. To keep everything simple used only few dependencies. This is output from `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] com.example:store:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:jar:1.4.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.json:json:jar:20160212:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.8:compile
```

Comment: Have you added the jar in Catalina?

Comment: `aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will answer my own question 'cause it seems to be working now. All dependencies that are necessary:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.10</version>
</dependency>
```

check if there is no duplicate dependencies (f.e. by `mvn dependency:tree`, use `<exclusions>` where necessary). Be sure you decorated your config class with `@EnableRetry`. For some reason you need to separate the caller from the method itself. F.e.this:

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 4, value = {ResourceAccessException.class}, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
public ResponseEntity<String> tryToSendAndReturnResponseByRestTemplate(final RestTemplate restTemplate,
                                                                       final HttpEntity<MyObjDTO>
                                                                               request) {

    return restTemplate.exchange(resolveUrl(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS), HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
}
```

goes to `SenderManager` class marked as f.e. `@Service` and in a different class f.e. `PhoneDirector` class you call:

```
senderManager.tryToSendAndReturnResponseByRestTemplate(restTemplate, request);
```

It should work. (If you need to specify what supposed to be returned if after `4` (only here) attempts you're still getting an exception, you can create another method (in `SenderManager` class) marked with `@Recover`, like this:

```
@Recover
public ResponseEntity<String> recoverWhenSendingMessageFailed(final ResourceAccessException e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
}
```

But If you needed args from `@Retryable` (in `@Recover` method) remeber that [arguments are populated from the argument list of the failed method in the same order as the failed method, and with the same return type](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)

Comment: It would be nice if you accept your answer. It seems like this question doesn’t have a correct answer yet.

Comment: That worked but I only used aspectjweaver without aop.

Answer (score 11):

It worked for me after adding the **spring-boot-starter-aop dependency** like below:

```
compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:1.5.10.RELEASE")
```

Answer (score 3):

spring-retry uses spring aop, make sure you have aop added in your pom and try clean building the application.

for spring app :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

for spring boot :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```